# What are some similar sounding synonyms for "master"?

Tags: synonyms

I'm actually looking for any word that implies a person who is skilled in a particular activity.

Comment: See [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/master) page.

Comment: Are you saying you want synonyms of 'master' that also _sound_ like master?

Comment: You can't ask for *any* word. That just means we become nothing more than a thesaurus—which you can use on your own. You need to clarify why one word is better suited than a different one, thereby allowing some kind of objective focus on a single word that is best for you.

Comment: I think I answered the question exactly as asked - not a bad answer either - why a down vote? Ah, this is like checkers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK then, to the question. The best that I can find is "maestro". It is similar in certain ways - the beginning of the word, syllables, a play on letters, and meaning etc. I hope it might work.

edit - along the same line, I then found "maven" too.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/master

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/maestro

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/maven